# problem with managing the Data with Routing in Angular

Tags: angular

i am beginner to Angular.

My code was working fine with the CRUD operation when without routing.

But when i added the routing i am not able to see the added value to my content table in another page.

May be inter Component communication problem. i'm not getting how to resolve this.

[image]

[image]

this is my HomeComponent .ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  name:string;
  DOB:number;
  mob:number;
  gender:string;
  title = 'Employee Information';


  employees = [
    {name:"Sikandar",DOB:"22-02-1996",mob:"4558965214",gender:"male"},
    {name:"Alex",DOB:"23-03-1995",mob:"4558965214",gender:"female"},
    {name:"Maria",DOB:"24-02-1994",mob:"9558965214",gender:"male"}
  ];
  model:any={};
  model2:any={};
  msg:any="";
  addEmployee(){
    this.employees.push(this.model);
    console.log(this.model);
    this.model = {};
   this.msg = "Record is successfully added..... "; 
  }
```

this is my ContentsComponent.ts

```
export class ContentsComponent implements OnInit {
  employees = [
    {name:"Sikandar",DOB:"22-02-1996",mob:"4558965214",gender:"male"},
    {name:"Alex",DOB:"23-03-1995",mob:"4558965214",gender:"female"},
    {name:"Maria",DOB:"24-02-1994",mob:"9558965214",gender:"male"}
  ];
  model:any={};
  model2:any={};
  msg:any="";

  private servers: {id: number, name: string, status: string}[] = [];

  constructor(private router:Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.servers = this.serversService.getEmplyee();
  }
  onReload(){
    this.router.navigate(['contents'],{relativeTo:this.route});
  }

  // getEmployee(){
  //   return this.employees;
  // }

  deleteEmployee(i){
    this.employees.splice(i,1);
    this.msg = "Record is successfully deleted..... ";    
  }

  myValue;
  editEmployee(k){
    this.model2.name = this.employees[k].name;
    this.model2.DOB=this.employees[k].DOB;
    this.model2.mob = this.employees[k].mob;
    this.model2.gender=this.employees[k].gender;
    // console.log(this.model.gender);
    this.myValue = k;

  }
  updateEmployee(){
    let k= this.myValue;
    this.model.gender = "female";
    for(let i=0; i<this.employees.length;i++){
      if(i==k){
        this.employees[i]= this.model2;
        this.model2 = {};       
        this.msg = "Record is successfully updated..... ";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Because in both of your components you have hard coded your employee list. So in contentscomponent the respective template is reading data from your contents component list

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow and angular community. You need to create a service which will emit data or you can store your `employees` object into the local storage and read it when your route is getting changed

Comment: i'm not getting How to use that approach exactly.